# Animating conditionally rendered components in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, conditional-rendering

I have a functional component that renders a div X or a divY depending if the props are undefined or not.

**Functional Component:**

```
const InfoHeader = (props) => {
    const {population, infected, recovered, deaths, active} = props
    
    return(
        //check if props are undefined
        !(Object.values(props).every(element => element !== undefined))
        ? 
        <div className="infoHeader-landing">
            ///render this div if props are undefined
        </div>
        : 
        <div className="infoHeader-wrapper">
           ///render this if props are not undefined
        </div>
    )
}

export default InfoHeader
```

When a user lands in the page the props will always be undefined until he/she interacts with a section of the map. I basically want to animate `infoHeader-landing` out once the user clicks on a section of the map.

I have tried setting an animate state on the parent component that renders `InfoHeader` and sets it to true once the user clicks the map and conditionally give a className to the div I want to animate out. Something like

```
<div className={props.animate ? "infoHeader-landing-slideOut" : "infoHeader-landing"}/>
```

I think this is happening because I'm re-rendering the entire component and therefore the animation does not apply but I'm unsure how to reach my goal in this situation, probably using useEffect?.

The animation would be something pretty simple like:

```
.infoHeader-landing-slideOut {
    animation-name: slideUp;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
    from {
        height: 30%;
    }

    to {
        height: 0%;
    }
}
```

Any help would be amazing,

Thanks